# How to recover deleted .swift file

Tags: ios, xcode

this question was probably asked before in some sort but I have a very weird issue in swift.
I left my project open for about a week in Xcode without working on it and today when I wanted to get back to it the main.storyboard is missing and the most important .swift file were I pretty much have all the code. 
How can I get that back? I have copies of the main.storyboard so it's probably not a big deal as I can revert to that but how can I recover the .swift file?

It's not in the app folder, it's not in the trash. 
The only way I can think of is to somehow recover it from the "Products" in Xcode were it Builds the app everytime you compile it. I do see the name of the file in there but it doesn't have a .swift extension but rather .o or .dia, .d, partial.swiftmodule etc. 
Is there any way I can decompile it somehow from the last successful project build?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not that it's going to help your problem now, but to help eliminate these problems in the future, you really should have [MacOS's built-in (and free) "Time Machine"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) turned on.

Comment: Also, put your project under version control with eg. git

Comment: thanks JustSid, I learned my lesson...it is now 4 days later and I started using the local git version control provided by swift...only if I knew about it earlier.... I see time machine as a huge pain in the arse and I wouldn't use it unless I wanted to backup my entire system to an external drive once a month. For Xcode projects, a git server would be the best option to prevent future "disasters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the source back without the original file, but you could get the header and method declarations back with something like [hopperapp.com](http://hopperapp.com), or any other decompiler (I personally have Dumper from the Mac App Store, but it costs money)

Comment: I tried all your suggestions and all decompilers as of today **for swift** cannot get your source back. 

For people reading this, if your source code was written in objective-c and you still have the .app file in your Xcode project under "Products" or your .app file is still intact in your simulator or your test device you can use something like class-dump to get your source back.